# java file receive stops

Tags: java, file-transfer, bufferedinputstream, bufferedoutputstream

I'm using **sockets** for **file transfer** in **java**.
Here is the **Client** code

```
for(int i = 0;i < fileList.size();i++) {
    String filename = (String)fileList.get(i);
    RequestFile(filename);

    try {
        BufferedOutputStream fileWriter = new BufferedOutputStream(
                                              new FileOutputStream(
                                                  new File(PROGRAM_PATH + "/" + 
                                                           filename)));         
        int packet;
        int count = 0;

        while((packet = fileReader.read()) != -1) {
            fileWriter.write(packet);
            count++;
        }

        System.out.println(filename + " receiver complete. (count : " + count + ")");
        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here is the **Server** code

```
public void SendFile(String filename) {
    try {
        fileReader = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(CLIENT_PATH + "/" + filename));

        int packet;
        int count = 0;
        while((packet = fileReader.read()) != -1) {
            count++;
            fileWriter.write(packet);
        }
        fileWriter.write(-1);
        System.out.println(count);

        fileReader.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I checked the **server's count**, it was `635`. It means the server had sent data `635` times.
However, the **client's print count** is only `512`. (from 0 to 511) I think it's stopped at `read()`, because

```
System.out.println(filename + " receiver complete. (count : " + count + ")");
```

is not printed. Can someone tell me the reason and solution?

Comment: I think you should use `packet` to increment `count` and check whether all the bytes are getting transferred or not.

Answer (score 0):

At the server side you can't send a byte with value `-1` to the client. This line:

```
fileWriter.write(-1);
```

It does not do what you want. The `write()` method will take the lowest 8 bits of the parameter and send that as one byte (which in this case will be `0xff`). At the client side `fileReader.read()` will receive this as `0xff` (of type `int`) and not as `-1` (of type `int`).

`-1` is a special value indicating that end of stream has been reached. It is not a valid data to be written or read. If you send `-1`, the client will read that as `0xff=255`. The values that can be sent and received is `0..255` both inclusive. Again, `-1` is a special value for end-of-stream.

At the server side you don't flush or close the output stream. That might explain the difference (data hold in the buffer might not get through to the client).